# twitter-bootstrap, issue with panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

With Bootstrap css I'm trying to build a panel using "panel" and "panel-primary" classes.
My issue is: the head of the panel (class panel-heading) doesn't take 100% of the width: https://jsfiddle.net/rcygfpxu/

my code is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="module panel panel-primary col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-9 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
            <div class="panel-heading">Subjet Line & Pre Header</div>
            <div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group inline-form row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2 control-label" for="subjectLine">Subject Line</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                        <input id="subjectLine" name="subjectLine" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group inline-form row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2 control-label" for="preHeader">Pre Header</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8">   
                        <input id="preHeader" name="preHeader" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just do not combine `panel` with `col-...`. Wrap `panel` in `col-...` instead.

Comment: That's because you're using Bootstraps grid columns, which add padding on the left and right. The panel is using 100% of the available width.

Comment: You need to remove col- because their paddings are interfering with your panels. You don't need to use col- inside panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

divide the panel div into 2 div - one for the panel and one for the columns

https://jsfiddle.net/rcygfpxu/4/

your version:

```
<div class="module panel panel-primary col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-9 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
```

new version:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-9 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
    <div class="module panel panel-primary">
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this style in your stylesheet, make sure you need to point those styles from your parent ID or Class, so that it wont effect bootstrap class.

```
.panel-primary {
  padding: 0;
}
```